# Linq to Entities не распознает метод

Tags: c#, entity-framework

когда я пытаюсь запустить

```
public static DalUser ToDalUser(this User ormUser)
    {
        return new DalUser()
        {
            Id = ormUser.Id,
            FirstName = ormUser.FirstName,
            LastName = ormUser.LastName,
            About = ormUser.About,
            Email = ormUser.Email,
            Password = ormUser.Password,
            Roles = ormUser.Roles.Select(role => role.ToDalRole())
        };
    }
```

выскакивает ошибка

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'DAL.Interface.DTO.DalUser ToDalUser(ORM.User)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

во вьюхе

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.About)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => item.Role)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

что не так? помогите, пожалуйста. уже весь интернет обрыскал - не нашел решения

Comment: Предварительно материализуйте объект, должно помочь

Comment: Зачем вы вообще привели код вьюхи - если достоверно известно, что на момент возникновения ошибки он даже не начинает выполняться?

Comment: @Bald подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно сделать. вроде пытался - не помогло.

Comment: @PavelMayorov как раз вот здесь и указывается,что выскакивает эксепшн

Comment: @PavelYakimovich ничего подобного, он выскакивает у вас раньше.

Comment: под материализацией обычно подразумевается получение заполненного данными экземпляра класса: `ToList()` для получения **списка**, либо `Single()` для получения **одного** объекта

Comment: @Bald пробовал уже Roles = ormUser.Roles.ToList().Select(role => role.ToDalRole()) и ToArray и AsEnumerable. ничего не помогает

Comment: а где в вашем примере `ormUser.Single()` || `ormUser.ToList()`???

Comment: сравните мой код со своим: `_context.User.Where(x=>x.Id==id).Include(x=>x.Roles).Single().ToDalUser();` Вам необходимо материализовать сущность `User` и только потом делать преобразование

Comment: @Bald спасибо большое! помогло!)

Answer (score 6):

`LINQ to Entities` - не поддерживает вызов пользовательских методов внутри себя, так как не может преобразовать запрос к фактической инструкции для исполнения. Иными словами Вам необходимо сначала получить данные, выгрузить их в память, к примеру вызвать [ToList()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx) или [ToArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb298736(v=vs.110).aspx) ну или [AsEnumerable()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx),а затем уже применить Ваш метод `ToDalUser` для полученных данных, к примеру через `.Select(x => ...ToDalUser...).ToList()`. И все будет работать.

И Вам правильно говорят, что падает оно не на представлении. Оно падает во время выборки (подготовки) данных.