# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

> Внимание! Это перевод вопроса [Linq to EntityFramework
>   DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4146300/5752652).
>
> Также смотри близкий по смыслу вопрос: [Linq to Entities не распознает
>   метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/556994/213987)

У меня есть приложение c# использующее Entity Framework.

Я делаю запрос к таблице `Article`, имеющей поле `startDate` и хочу получить записи из базы, которые удовлетворяют условиям `DateTime.Now > startDate` и `(startDate + period) > DateTime.Now`:

```
Context.Article
    .Where(p => p.StartDate < DateTime.Now)
    .Where(p => p.StartDate.AddDays(p.Period) > DateTime.Now)
```

При запуске этого кода я получаю ошибку:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Как это исправить?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4146300/5752652

Answer (score 7):

Когда происходит выполнение Linq-запроса, ваши условия в where, которые записаны на языке c# должны быть преобразованы в SQL-запрос и в ошибке сообщается о том, что LINQ to Entities неизвестно, как преобразовывать `AddDays` из c# кода в код SQL.

Есть два варианта решения этой проблемы.

Первый вариант подразумевает, что вы отказываетесь от того, чтобы выполнять эти условия на сервере и перенесёте на клиент. Так как Linq To Objects знает, как обработать AddDays - то ошибка пропадёт:

```
Context.Article.Where(p => p.StartDate < DateTime.Now)
               .ToList()
               .Where(p => p.StartDate.AddDays(p.Period) > DateTime.Now);
```

Минусы этого подхода очевидны: вы качаете лишние данные с SQL-сервера в память клиента и эти расходы могут быть весьма значительны.

Например, в данном примере когда нужно выбрать статьи за определённый промежуток времени вы должны будете сначала забрать всю таблицу к себе в память, а потом только уже отфильтровать.

А вот если бы у вас запрашивался список статей какого-то определённого автора за интервал времени, то вероятно этой дополнительной нагрузкой для клиента можно было бы пренебречь.

Второй вариант решения подразумевает, что у вас версия .Net 4.0 или выше и вы можете воспользоваться [EntityFunctions.AddDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412479.aspx):

```
Context.Article.Where(p => p.StartDate < DateTime.Now)
               .Where(p => EntityFunctions.AddDays(p.StartDate, p.Period)
                   > DateTime.Now);
```

В данном подходе sql-выражение выполняется на сервере, поэтому этот вариант решения является более предпочтительным.

Разумеется, помимо AddDate в EntityFunctions есть и определения для других функций.

В EF6 вместо EntityFunctions вам следует использовать аналог – DbFunctions, например для AddDays есть [аналог](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220066%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

Это то, что касается стандартных классов .Net, которые присутствуют в фреймворке. [Сходная ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/556994/213987) может проявляться для ваших собственных функций, которые неизвестно как приводить к SQL на сервере.

Answer (score 1):

Класс EntityFunctions был заменен на класс DbFunctions.
Я использовала код:

```
Context.Article.Where(p => p.StartDate < DateTime.Now)
               .Where(p => DbFunctions.AddDays(p.StartDate, p.Period) > DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: здесь принято общаться на русском. переведите, пожалуйста, ваш ответ.

Comment: Верно! В EF6 используются DbFunctions, я писал об этом. Спасибо за пример!