# Подсчёт количества записей принадлежащих промежутку времени

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Есть таблица, в которой хранятся просмотры:

```
+----+------------------+---------+----------------------------+
| id | media_content_id | user_id |                   view_date|
+----+------------------+---------+----------------------------+
|  1 |                1 |       6 | 2020-11-11 02:25:48.166839 |
|  2 |                1 |       3 | 2020-11-11 02:25:48.167086 |
|  3 |                1 |       9 | 2020-11-10 23:25:48.167342 |
+----+------------------+---------+----------------------------+
```

Класс используемый в EF:

```
[Table("media_views")]
public class MediaView
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("media_contents")]
    [Column("media_content_id")]
    public int MediaContentId {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("user")]
    [Column("user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Column("view_date")]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Нужно получить список данных в виде промежутков времени и количества просмотров в них.

Я решил эту задачу следующим образом:

```
var iteratingDateTime = videoViews.OrderBy(vv => vv.DateTime).First().DateTime;
var currentDateTime = this.dateTimeProvider.Now();
var viewsAtSpan = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();
var hoursSpan = 1;

while (iteratingDateTime < currentDateTime)
{
    var views = videoViews.Where(
        vv => vv.DateTime > iteratingDateTime && 
              vv.DateTime < iteratingDateTime.AddHours(hoursSpan));
    viewsAtSpan.Add(iteratingDateTime, views.Count());
    iteratingDateTime = iteratingDateTime.AddHours(hoursSpan);
}
```

Но очевидно, что это очень плохое решение, потому что будет огромное количество обращений к базе данных.
Я могу получить данные с помощью SQL-запроса:

```
SELECT media_content_id, DATE(view_date), HOUR(view_date), COUNT(*) FROM media_views
WHERE media_content_id = 1
GROUP BY media_content_id, Date(view_date), HOUR(view_date);
```

```
+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+
| media_content_id | Date(view_date) | Hour(view_date) | COUNT(*)|
+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+
|                1 |      2020-11-09 |              13 |       1 |
|                1 |      2020-11-09 |              14 |       3 |
|                1 |      2020-11-09 |              15 |       1 |
+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------+
```

Но никак не могу сообразить как получить похожий результат с помощью `Entity framework core`.

Comment: Почему вы не хотите использовать просто `videoViews.Count(vv => vv.DateTime > iteratingDateTime &&  vv.DateTime < iteratingDateTime.AddHours(hoursSpan));)`? Как по мне - вы столкнётесь вот с этим, но это решаемо: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/785029/213987

Comment: @AK  Если я правильно понимаю, то в таком случае будет большое количество запросов к базе, равное `currentDateTime` - `iteratingDateTime)` "поделёное" на `hoursSpan` (при каждом вызове `.Count()`).

Comment: А зачем вам цикл? Вы сказали в заголовке, что у вас есть временной интервал, т.е. есть дата начала и дата конца, эти два параметра как раз и задают условие `vv.DateTime > ДатаНачалаИнтервала` и `vv.DateTime < ДатаКонцаИнтервала`, зачем вдруг цикл?

Comment: @AK Я плохо озаглавил вопрос :( В самом теле вопроса я указал, что мне нужны промежутки и просмотры: "Нужно получить список данных в виде промежутков времени и количества просмотров в них."

Comment: То есть у вас на входе набор интервалов времени и нужно вернуть словарь из интервал - количество попаданий? Приведите в вопросе пример входных данных и что ожидаете на выходе увидеть.

Comment: @AK на входе у меня записи с  "точными" датами (не промежутками), а получить нужно да словарь из <интервал, количество попаданий>

Comment: То есть на входе у вас `var source = new List<DateTime>()
{
 DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5),
 DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1),
 DateTime.Today.AddDays(0),
 DateTime.Today.AddDays(4),
};` и вы ожидаете что для каждого дня из списка нужно от 00:00 до 23:59 найти количество попаданий?

Comment: @AK да, примерно так.

Answer (score 3):

Есть решение для ситуации, когда временные промежутки равны целому дню:

Я создал дополнительный класс, который буду заполнять данными:

```
public class AggregatedMediaViewsOverTime
{
    public int MediaContentId { get; set; }

    public int Views { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Получить данные можно c помощью такого LINQ запроса:

```
var test = from mv in db.MediaViews
           where mv.MediaContentId == mediaContentId
           group mv by mv.DateTime.Date into grp
           select new AggregatedMediaViewsOverTime()
           {
               Views = grp.Count(),
               MediaContentId = mediaContentId,
               Date = grp.Key.Date
           };
```

или в функциональной форме:

```
var test2 = db.MediaViews
    .Where(mv => mv.MediaContentId == mediaContentId)
    .GroupBy(mv => mv.DateTime.Date)
    .Select(grp => new AggregatedMediaViewsOverTime()
    {
        Views = grp.Count(),
        MediaContentId = mediaContentId,
        Date = grp.Key.Date
    });
```

Данный запрос конвертируется в следующий SQL запрос:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Views`, @__mediaContentId_0 AS `MediaContentId`, CONVERT(CONVERT(`m`.`view_date`, date), date) AS `Date`
FROM `media_views` AS `m`
WHERE `m`.`media_content_id` = @__mediaContentId_0
GROUP BY CONVERT(`m`.`view_date`, date)
```