# Как работает AutoMapper с EF?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

Не много не понимаю, как работает вот это:

```
await context.Objects
                        .Where(x=> x.Name!= null)
                        .Select(x => _mapper.Map<Object2>(x))
                        .Where(filter)
                        .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Фильтр — это вот это `Expression<Func<Object2, bool>> filter`

А именно, каким образом срабатывает AutoMapper, если запрос еще нематериализован => крутится на стороне СУБД.

Вместо х  в этом месте  `_mapper.Map<Object2>(x)`, какой-то фейковый объект, который мапитья и после этого разбираются результаты мапинга и все это транслируется в Sql?

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/23.4.php

Comment: Я не специалист по Automapper. Но разве там не должен стоять `ProjectTo<Object2>()`? А то у меня есть подозрение что этот мапинг не эффективен.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю вопрос здесь есть два смысловых слоя.

Первый мне кажется вы вполне понимаете — про разницу между IEnumerable и IQueryable.

Запросы которые можно выполнить на сервере (а у вас везде так, раз вы работаете с `Expression<Func`) выполнятся на сервере.

Например, вот запрос:

```
this.EntryForms
    .Where(x => x.Status == 0)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Json = x.Json } )
    .Dump();
```

Смотришь в linqpad какой код - на клиент читаются все поля таблицы:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 0
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[CreateDate], [t0].[ModifyDate], [t0].[Attempts], [t0].[Status], [t0].[Json]
FROM [EntryForms] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Status] = @p0
```

Но если убрать `.AsEnumerable()` с сервера читаются только два нужных на клиенте поля:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 0
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Json]
FROM [EntryForms] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[Status] = @p0
```

Провайдер умеет разбирать expression и транслировать их в Sql. (Ну или не умеет, тогда вы получите ошибку - [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/785029/213987))

Второй момент (и это уже как раз про автомаппер) это то, что автомаппер при построении проекции умеет работать с `Expression<Func` и в частности dto'шки умеет трансформировать в выражения ([тынц](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection.EFCore)):

> Note: This is done by converting the OrderDTO to
> Expression<Func<Order,bool>> and using that to find matching type in
> the database. You can also map objects to expressions as well.
>
> Persist doesn't call submit changes automatically