# Мапинг моделей в разных запросах ORM

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, nhibernate

Вопрос по ORM

```
Select(x => new Model1 {
  Id = x.Id,
  Name = x.FullName,
  Model2 = new Model2 {
    Id = x.Entity2.Id,
    Name = x.Entity2.Name
  }
}
```

Скажем есть вот такой запрос, проблема в том, что если мне надо будет использовать Model2 в 20 запросах, то это будет 20 копипастов. Если использовать для мапинга метод, то он будет вызываться на каждой строке запроса. Можно ли как то унифицировать мапинг модели средствами .net?

Comment: Смотрели Automapper? https://habr.com/en/post/444934/

Comment: `если мне надо будет использовать Model2 в 20 запросах, то это будет 20 копипастов` - Можете, пожалуйста, привести пример? Я не понимаю, чем вам методы не угодили

Comment: @AndreiKhotko если в запросе будет 20 строк, то к примеру метод MapModel2(entity), который будет вызываться для каждой строки, спровоцирует 20 запросов к бд

Comment: @AK Automapper скорее всего сработает, но на одной родительской модельке (Model1 в нашем случае) могут получаться разные данные с сущности, поэтому очень желательно средствами .net, возможно там требуются какие то манипуляции с деревом, но я в этом не силен

Comment: Зависит от запроса, может и не спровоцирует (в случае использования автомаппера - точно), а для простеньких запросов и без автомаппера может сообразить, обсуждали недавно здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1219610/ Как будет в случае с вашим конкретным запросом - не знаю, по-хорошему надо бы привести точные описания классов, чтобы быть уверенным, что мы оба говорим об одном и том же запросе.

Comment: @AK я правильно понимаю, если прописать `Model2 = _mapper.Map<Model2>(x.Entity2)` внутри запроса, то все сработает в одном запросе?

Comment: Не совсем так, вам надо будет мапнуть Model1, а остальное уже автомаппер разберётся как мапать дочерние объекты. Вы бы знаете что? Написали бы подробнее что у вас за вопрос, что за модели, потому что я так понимаю, осваивать автомаппер вдумчиво и последовательно у вас нет времени (а любой инструмент надо осваивать, иначе постоянно будете сталкиваться с проблемами), но думаете, что вас вопрос понятен посетителям сайта. Я вот например уже который раз смотрю и думаю, а нет ли у вас вообще ошибки проектирования, что вы вообще на эту проблему вышли?

Comment: @AK в проекте используется Automapper, просто его не везде можно применить, например у сущности `Entity1` есть `FullName` и `ShortName`, соответственно в определенных кейсах мы можем в `Model1.Name` мапнуть либо `FullName`, либо `ShortName`. По правильному возможно надо было бы завести 2 модельки, одна с `ShortName`, а другая с `FullName`. Но `Model1` много где используется с тонной логики, в итоге мне нужен способ который делает универсальным мапинг `Model2`, не затрагивая `Model1`

Comment: Не в обиду, но знаете (мне да и многим) не очень интересно неделями вытягивать из автора вопроса существенные подробности. В основном постоянные участники сайта смотрят текущие вопросы и быстро отвечают на то, что знают -- и если автор не хочет пояснять, что у него есть или слишком долго отвечает -- проще просто оставить в сторону и ответить на три других вопроса. Вы только-только начинаете хоть что-то рассказывать о своей проблеме, причём уже несколько иной (изначально даже сам факт знакомства и использования автомаппер скрыли), ну что ж... может кто-нибудь прочитает вопрос спустя полгода.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используйте `.Select()` после `.AsQueryable()`, то вся веборка будет сделана в БД и затем возвращена в память. Если после `.AsEnumerable()`, то сначала все придет в память, и уже в этих загруженных данных сделается выборка. В обоих случаях к базе идет 1 запрос.

Comment: ответ не по теме, но все равно спасибо. а вообще в случае использования lazy loading вполне возможна ситуация создания кучи подзапросов

Comment: я так понял вопрос)