# Как узнать SQL, который отправляет Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Использую модель ADO.NET. Пишу запросы в базу на LINQ, а как узнать SQL-запрос, в который они переводятся? Какое расширение установить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1412863/5752652 + можно посмотреть через SSMS (Profiler), либо в linqpad хорошо видно на закладке "Sql" (примеры которые я писал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219672/213987) как раз из него даны).

Comment: @AK А есть какое то расширение, удобное, юзабилитишное?)

Comment: @AK Спасибо !  )

Comment: [Logging and intercepting database operations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception)