# Как следить, за тем куда уходит память?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, отладка, производительность

Как проследить куда уходит RAM?
И куда смотреть когда при старте сразу тратится 500мб RAM?

[image: Затрата памяти при старте приложения]

Наибольшие сомнения вызывает следующая запись:

```cs
var balls = dbContext.TrainingObjects
    .Include(a => a.UserDetails)
    .ThenInclude(a => a.ApplicationUser)
    .ToList()
    .Where(a => a.Activity && a.Balls != 0 && (begin <= a.GetTime() && end >= a.GetTime()))
    .GroupBy(a => a.ApplicationUserId)
    .Select(a =>
        new BallRes
        {
            IdAccount = a.FirstOrDefault().UserDetails.ApplicationUser.Id,
            Username = a.FirstOrDefault().UserDetails.ApplicationUser.UserName,
            Image = a.FirstOrDefault().UserDetails.ApplicationUser.ImgSrc,
            Name = a.FirstOrDefault().UserDetails.ApplicationUser.FullName,
            Rank = a.FirstOrDefault().UserDetails.ApplicationUser.Rang,
            Point = a.Sum(e => e.Balls)
        }).OrderByDescending(a => a.Point).ToList();
```

Возможно ли как-то это оптимизировать?

Comment: https://habr.com/en/company/otus/blog/536942/

Comment: Следите за тем, что вы создаете с помощью `new` и в каких количествах. Быть может некоторые объекты можно переиспользовать, а не пересоздавать. Способов рефакторинга множество, но они сильно зависят от конкретного кода. Если у вас есть конкретный фрагмент кода, который по-вашему мнению кушает много оперативы, покажите его в вопросе.

Comment: [Profiling documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @aepot,я добавил код, но я немного не понимаю, с чем может быть проблема

Comment: Первый `ToList()` явно грузит много данных из БД в память. Уберите его.

Comment: Вы первым же .ToList качаете всю таблицу TrainingObjects на клиентскую машину, его следует убрать либо хотя бы поставить после Where, чтобы меньше записей грузило. C датами могут возникнуть проблемы типа такой: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/785029/213987 Ну и группировку вы делаете на клиенте, а могли бы на sql сервере сделать и сортировку и группировку. В общем, запрос весьма неоптимальный и крайне плохо написанный со всеми этими a.FirstOrDefault() Я не уверен, что это единственное бутылочное горлышко в приложении, но этот запрос действительно выглядит требующим переделки.

Comment: @aepot, Понял, кажется из за ToList много памяти тратится

Comment: @aepot, Спсибо!! Да я уже изменил обращение в БД. Начинаю разбираться. Тут, бд немного приходится переписывать, но думаю, с этими функциями, которым можно обращаться. Будет намного лучше. Еще раз спасибо

Comment: Вы наверное к другому пользователю хотели обратиться  а обратились ко мне. @AK

Comment: aepot, ДА вы правы. Ну вам тоже)
@AK, Какой раз мне помогает