# Linq to Entites не распознает методы по работе с регулярными выражениями

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Имеется `IQueryable<Car>`, к которой делаю такой запрос

```
Regex reg = new Regex("\\b(" + item.Replace('*', '.') + "){1}\\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

cars = cars.Where(x => !reg.IsMatch(x.CarNumber));
```

Еще пробовал вот так:

```
cars = from obj in cars
       where !reg.IsMatch(obj.CarNumber)
       select obj;
```

В регулярном выражении проблем не вижу, я его писал на всяких `regex` тест сайтах.

Что можно сделать в таком случае? Считаю что `regex` тут упрощает жизнь и не хотелось бы от него отказываться. Приводить в `List` запрос не нужно, он еще позже будет использоваться.

Comment: Провайдер linq не умеет транслировать подобные выражения в SQL код ([тынц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/785029/213987))

А не умеет он потому что SQL сервер не умеет нативно в регэкспы, надо свои CLR procedure писать ([пример](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/)).

Comment: См. [DbFunctions.Like](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.like?view=entity-framework-6.2.0). https://stackoverflow.com/a/16740796/5045688