# как с помощью linq вернуть время в промежутке

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Мне нужно отнять от даты последнего визита дату регистрации.
`var livespan = DB.Users.Where(x => x.DateRegistration - x.DateLastVisit);`
я пытался сделать что то такое, но это ошибочно
у меня есть дата регистрации и дата последнего визита, лишь нужно найти между ними разницу и вернуть неё

```
public DateTime DateRegistration { get; set; }  public DateTime DateLastVisit { get; set; }
```

Например время в промежутке от даты регистрации до даты последнего визита.
какой оператор используется, для того, чтобы рассчитать именно промежуток времени?
например Where(DateRegrstration Between DateLastVisit)
Я выполняю запрос через лямбду:
`DB.Users.Where(x=>x.DateLastVisit && c.DateRegistration);`

но  &  нельзя использовать

Comment: Случайное время? Дополните вопрос примерами, и покажите вашу попытку решить задачу. Что именно не получается?

Comment: @theacidday если вам нужно узнать разницу дат последнего визита и регистрации **конкретного юзера**, вам сначала нужно его выбрать (например, если известен его `userId`, то можно так: `var user = DB.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);` А затем уже `var livespan = user.DateLastVisit - user.DateRegistration;` Вы получите `TimeSpan` - время в промежутке (то, что вы и просите).

Comment: В коде я вижу `DB` - это контекст Entity Framework? Отредактируйте вопрос, указав, какую именно ORM вы используете: EF или EF Core (и точную версию!)

Answer (score 1):

```
(Date2 - Date1).TotalSeconds
```

можно любую интервальность выбрать

Comment: Автор явно использует Entity Framework. Там такая конструкция не будет работать.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу:

```
.Where(x => x > DateRegistration && x > DateLastVisit)
```

Просто понимаете в чём проблема? Невозможно, чтобы DateLastVisit была больше чем дата регистрации: сначала регистрируемся, потом заходим.

Во-вторых, у вас всегда будет две даты, скажем, дата последнего визита и DateTime.Now.

Так что надо уточнить, что за даты, но в любом случае, у вас есть Date1 и Date2:

```
.Where(x => x > Date1 && x < Date2)
```

---

> типо нужно как то отнять от даты ласт визита дату регистрации чтобы понять вемя продолжительности жизни юзера

Интервалы - это тип [TimeSpan](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.8), он делается очень просто и без linq:

```
TimeSpan userLifetime = DateTime.Now - DateRegistration;
```

И у типа TimeSpan есть множество вариантов методов https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timespan.minutes?view=netframework-4.8 - например TimeSpan.Hours или TimeSpan.Minutes или те же самые функции с префиксом Total

---

> Да, но мне нужно узнать разницу именно от готового юзера, ведь данные о юзере хранятся в бд, и чтобы получить к ним доступ мне нужно использовать LINQ.

@theacidday Ну вот и смотрите, у вас у пользователя в БД есть два параметра: DateRegistration  и DateLastVisit причём второе больше первого и оба меньше DateTime.Now. И что вы хотите за выборку? "Пользователи у которых дата регистрации меньше даты последнего визита"? Наивно. "Пользователи у которых дата последнего захода меньше чем сейчас"? Наивно. Как ни крути, у вас нет ДВУХ дат, а значит, нет ИНТЕРВАЛА ДАТ.

Вам нужно сфомулировать логичное условие отбора, вероятно это "пользователи зарегистрированные более месяца назад" тогда
.Where(x => x.DateRegistration > DateTime.Today.AddMonth(-1)`

или "разница дат последнего захода и регистрации больше 1 года", но вот не всегда на сайтах так сильно морочатся - иногда просто смотрят на дату регистрации и текущую дату. Вот об этом был мой комментарий, что нет особого смысла так морочиться.

PS Возможно пригодится при расчёте дат на сервере: [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddDays(Double)'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/785029/213987)

Comment: типо нужно как то отнять от даты ласт визита дату регистрации чтобы понять вемя продолжительности жизни юзера

Comment: Нужно вроде от даты LastVisit отнять DateRegistration

Comment: @theacidday Можно и так, зависит от договорённостей на сайте.

Comment: Да, но мне нужно узнать разницу именно от готового юзера, ведь данные о юзере хранятся в бд, и чтобы получить к ним доступ мне нужно использовать LINQ.

Comment: У меня есть информация о последнем входе и о дате регистрации, мне лишь нужно получить разницу, то есть промежуток между датой регистрации(например: 20.10.2000) и датой последнего визита(например:20.10.2001), соответственно разница 1 год, но мне еще нужно так сделать со всеми Юзерами, я думал пройти через цикл где for (int i = 0; i <= DB.Users.Count(); i++) чтобы вернуть во View продолжительность жизни всех пользователей и сделать из этого диаграмму. т.е. нужно в контроллер вернуть массив, или принимать в метод, который высчитывает из даты ласт визита и регистрации вот это промежуточное время

Comment: @theacidday А как насчёт чего-то типа `db.Users.Where(x => (x.DateLastVisit - x.DateRegistration) > TimeSpan.FromDays(365))`? [тынц дока](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromdays?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: я новичек в программировании, если можно подскажите для чего  ```> Time.Span.FromDays(365)```

Comment: @theacidday Разница двух типов DateTIme будет типа TimeSpan (тот самый "интервал"), поэтому мы сравниваем интервал с интервалом в 365 дней, очень семантично выглядит.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan? result = list.Where(w => w.Id == 1)
   .Select(s => (TimeSpan?)(s.DateLastVisit - s.DateRegistration))
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Локальный пример:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRegistration { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateLastVisit { get; set; }
}
List<User> list = new List<User>();
list.Add(new User() { Id = 1, DateLastVisit = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(1), DateRegistration = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(3) });
TimeSpan? result = list.Where(w => w.Id == 1).Select(s => (TimeSpan?)(s.DateLastVisit - s.DateRegistration)).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Вывод: `2.00:00:00 //2 дня`
Если пользователя нет (Id == 0): `null`